# email server on external server and webhost on our server

Tags: smtp, webserver, remote-server

We have a small business and we are providing webhosting, our isp is blocking smtp port (troubleshoted on lot of forums, by isp and others) no way to solve it.
So i wondering if is posible to make email server to point somewhere else.

sample.com loads website on IP XY.SD.SD.GH
@sample.com connects to IP ZZ.UU.VV.DD

for multiple domains (for every webhost that we are providing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to define which host is the email host in the DNS records.

How you have to do that depends on your DNS provider, but normally its quite simple adding a MX record pointing to the mailserver you want to use.

In more detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record

Usually this is no problem at all to have them seperated and a lot of people do it using services different from their webhosting provider like Gmail and so on.

Comment: thank you, i know how to edit dns records, i was only not sure if it will work :-)